# Why is the number of heads and the number of tails independent in $n$ coin flips?

Tags: probability, random-variables, intuition

In probability, in different manifestations, I have noticed that the sum of random variables $X$ and $Y$ may be given as $n$, and yet $X$ and $Y$ may still be independent. I find this very counter intuitive. If $Y = n - X$, how can it be independent of $X$?

For example, if I flip a coin 10 times, are the number of heads and the number of tails independent? It doesn't quite make sense for them to be to me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: They're not independent. What gave you the idea they were?

Comment: I was just trying to think of a situation where the sum of random variables was fixed ($X + Y = n$.) If I have 10 coin flips, I know the number of heads and the number of tails will sum to 10. But it still doesn't seem logical for them to be independent, as you confirmed.

Comment: Yeah. And they're not independent. So what's your question?

Comment: A lecture example, for instance, ask me to find the conditional pmf of $X_1$ given $X_1 + X_2 = m$ if $X_1 \sim \text{Bin}(n_1, p)$ and $X_2 \sim \text{Bin}(n_2, p).$ It also says $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.

Comment: My question is: If $X_1 + X_2 = m$, how can $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent?

Comment: If we're talking about dice and I asked you "what's the probability you roll a 1 given the number you roll is less than 4?" you wouldn't think to yourself "huh that's weird that dice only ever roll numbers less than 4, I would have thought that sometimes they roll higher numbers." You are not told that $X_1+X_2=m$ is always true, you are asked to find the probability that $X_1=k$ conditional on the event $X_1+X_2=m$.

Comment: What you're saying is that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not [conditionally independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence) given the event $X_1 + X_2 = m$.  That is true, but $X_1$ and $X_2$ can still be (unconditionally) independent; there is no contradiction between those statements.